# No se restringe el acceso al usuario si no ha confirmado su email, usando Laravel UI y MustVerifyEmail en Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando la última versión de Laravel y hago los siguientes pasos (previamente instalé Laravel UI):

En el modelo `User` implementé `MustVerifyEmail`

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

y habilité en el modelo `User`

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

Agregué `verify` a `routes`

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Pero al iniciar sesión el usuario llega al `dashboard` sin verificar su `email` no lo restringe